# How to set this kind of breakpoint in ollydbg?

Tags: breakpoints, ollydbg

I want to break on where `Executable Module X` is called, but I've no idea which function is actually called.

Is it possible to set this kind of matching-all breakpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a memory breakpoint on its code section.

Comment: But I don't know which line of code section is actually executed.

Comment: @ollydbg, Alt-E, select module, click right mouse button, "View memory", select ".text" section, F2, F9

Comment: @ollydbg, also read PE format spec, olly help file, google, etc

Comment: I'll sound dumb, but I see no "View memory" in OllyDbg2, only "view code in CPU", "View data in CPU", and "view executable file". Has it been discarded/renamed/requires a specific option?